# Jquery DIalog Stack stays on top of overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having trouble with jQuery ui-dialog plugin. What happens is, whenever I have two or more dialogs stacked, the overlay of each dialog goes to the back of ALL the dialogs, and thus none of them are blocked.

Versions:

**Jquery:** 1.10.2

**Jquery-ui:** 1.11.1

How I open them:

```
function openDialog($divDialog, options){
    var optionsDefault = {
        modal : true,
        autoOpen : true,
        resizable : false,
        closeOnEscape : true,
        close: function(){
            $divDialog.dialog('destroy');
        }
    };
    $.extend( true, optionsDefault, options );
    $divDialog.dialog(optionsDefault);
    $divDialog.dialog( "moveToTop" );
    $divDialog.position({
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: window
    });
}
```

[image: One dialog, overlay is thin, you can see clearly through]

[image: Two dialogs, there are two overlays in the back, so it's darker, and first dialog is not covered, you can interact with it]

I think I'm missing something basic about dialog stacking, so hopefully you can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please fix screeshots

Comment: @AlexFilatov screenshots are fine unblurring them will not contribute to the understanding of the question, the relevant info is clearly visible. elithin, jquery dialogs are designed to always be topmost. you need to change their z-index after you initiate the dialogs if you want to alter this behavior.

Comment: @Banana, the dialog stacking problem i solved with the "moveToTop" method of the plugin. The problem is that the overlay of the dialog should be created on top of every content, including other dialogs rigth?

Comment: @elithin im not sure, but if you inspect them you will notice the z-index difference. i think the dialogs are designed to always be on top of the overlays, even if it means other dialog's overlays. you can just select the overlay and change its z-index to be more than the old dialog.

Comment: @Banana, I find that neither dialog has z-index, while both overlays have the same z-index (999) if I add one to one overlay, it comes on top of the dialogs. COuld it be that I have to manually manage z-index of everything?

Comment: @elithin i might be wrong, but from what ive seen so far, jquery dialogs dont take into consideration irregular things like dialog on top of dialog, or a dropdown box inside a dialog, etc. check the jquery dialog documentation and if it doesnt mention built in z index control, then i suppose we have to do it ourselves.

Comment: @Banana ok, thanks for your time. I'll read the docs again and maybe try to upgrade or start over with a clean build of jquery-ui.